# What is the original source of the problem of finding equivalent resistance between two nodes in an infinite grid of resistors?

Tags: physics, reference-request, electricity, resource-recommendation, book-recommendation

A famous problem in electronics or physics course,is the following---

Consider an infinite 2d grid of resistors having resistance of equal value.Find the resistance between any two nodes in the grid.

This problem has been discussed in nerd sniping,and in-

1.https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/
and

2.https://www.mbeckler.org/resistor_grid/
and

3.https://sites.google.com/site/resistorgrid/node1
and

4.https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath668/kmath668.htm

Simpler versions of this often crops up in various college/university/competitive exams,and is now-a-days considered a "famous" problem---
(see last paragraph of https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath668/kmath668.htm)

Interestingly,I could not find it's reference in most classic circuit analysis/electronics textbooks! So,How did it rise to popularity and what is the original source of this?Did this come up on the internet or excercise of some book or otherwise?

Comment: I strongly doubt there's a single "originator" of this  class of problems.  There may be a "first" instance of publication in a text book.

Comment: *Did this come up on the internet* --- You're kidding, right? The internet has only been around for 25 some years (close to 40 if you count newsgroups). Possibly relevant is the fact that Madelung's paper was published in 1918, this being the paper involving the solid state physics computations we now call the [Madelung constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_constant).